# JSON serialization strategy for dates

Tags: java, json, serialization

The problem I am having is that I have some consumers that are Java and some that are browsers. My target browsers are IE7+ (json3 for IE7 only) & Chrome.

For a browser I wish to have the date deserialize to a `Date` JavaScript object (using the `JSON.parse()` method. For a Java consumer I wish to deserialize to a `java.util.Date` Java object.

Given that I can't change anything on the browser side. I have to do serialize the messages to something like this:

`{ myDate: new Date(<EPOCH HERE>) }`

Which of course will cause a problem for Java deserializer. However, I am hoping there is something I can do with `Gson` to make this work...amy ideas?

Or should I take a different strategy altogether?

Answer (score 4):

I usually use the annotation `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` to deal with this problem. I also use ISO8601 format as a standard for our REST API dates.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDateDeserializer.class)
private Date expiryDate;
```

**JsonDateSerializer** class

```
@Component
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    // ISO 8601
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

**JsonDateDeserializer** class

```
@Component
public class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    // ISO 8601
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try
        {
            return dateFormat.parse(jsonParser.getText());
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            throw new JsonParseException("Could not parse date", jsonParser.getCurrentLocation(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have a separate parser in your browser code?

Comment: @Cheetah yes indeed ;) I don't know what you are using, but you if you use JQuery or AngularJS is straightforward.