# Posting a java.util.Date array to a RestEasy service

Tags: java, arrays, jackson, resteasy, json-deserialization

I am trying to send an array of Date objects (java.util.Date) to my REST service. I keep getting the following error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Date[] 
out of VALUE_STRING token
at [Source: wt.servlet.ServletRequestMonitor$CountingInputStream@3a03e75d; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Here is the prototype of my method:

```
@POST
@Path("/invitations/{userId}/{inviteeId}")
public Response updateDelegations(@PathParam("userId") String userId, 
        @PathParam("inviteeId") String delegateeId, Date[] invitedOnDates) throws Exception
{
    // more code to process this request
}
```

Here is the json that is being sent:

```
{
   "invitedOnDates":["2014-08-05T00:00:00.000Z","2014-08-06T00:00:00.000Z","2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"]
}
```

I also tried instead posting a String array, even that resulted in the same JsonMappingException.

Googling hasn't helped me much. Any pointer are welcome.

Comment: You should at least post the JSON that you're sending. Also, read http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Comment: Sorry - updated the post include json that is being sent.

Comment: Have you read the link I posted? It says that dates are serialized as numbers by default, and explains how to configure Jackson to specify a date format.

Comment: I going through it right now. Another suggestion I got was to wrap the Date object in a class - lets say DateItem (either as String or epoch long value) and pass the array of DateItem. Sound a bit roundabout.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet for the document link. Managed to solve the issue by wrapping the date in a class and then using custom serializer (@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)) for the date property.

Comment: For anyone else looking for JsonDateSerializer, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405975/json-serialization-strategy-for-dates

Answer (score 0):

not a good idea to post Date object as it is. Wont work. use a transformer/serializer to convert Date to string, preferably using a DateFormatter, then send as String and convert back on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Resteasy's Java 8 date plugin (JSR-310) if you can. you can use either a year-month-day formatted string, or an array representing the numbers, e.g with a little demo application with the following immutable value object defined...

```
class Person {
    private final UUID id;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String middleNames;
    private final LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @JsonCreator
    public Peron(
            @JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
            @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
            @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
            @JsonProperty("middleNames") String middleNames,
            @JsonProperty("dateOfBirth") LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleNames = middleNames;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    // getter ceremony omitted
}
```

And a controller/resource like this...

```
@Path("/api")
public class PersonResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/person")
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person addPerson(Person person) {
        // do something with new person
    }
}
```

Then the following curls with either date format should work quite happily:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"dateOfBirth":[2009,12,15]}' \
   http://localhost:8000/api/person

curl -v -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"dateOfBirth":"2009-12-15"}' \
   http://localhost:8000/api/person
```

The main annoyance I've found is that serialization of dates results in this array [year,month,day], which on the JS side I end up having to pack into a JS Date object (in the model) or a flat string (in a form). Ah well! Hope this helps.